# Error in reading project with delimited text layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, csv

I have multiple QGIS maps with a KML vector layer and a delimited text layer on top (csv file). I want to save these maps as images using a script as follows in the python console to do this.

```
for project_name in projects:
    QgsProject.instance().setFileName(project_name + '.qgs')
    QgsProject.instance().read()
    # Save content of map canvas as image
    qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(project_name + '.png')
```

However, the projects are not being read with the error regarding the delimited text layer which is:

> File cannot be opened or delimiter parameters are not valid.

This is not the case when I open the project manually in the QGIS UI. The projects loads correctly and also gets saved as an image.

Edit: I upgraded from QGIS 2.8 to 2.18 and now it throws a dialog box which is a 'Handle Bad layers' one. I don't understand why that is when all the file paths are correct and the project opens normally outside the console.